# What's the preferred method for accessing Azure table storage from a UWP app?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, uwp

UWP apps are supported by the Azure Storage SDK, but only a few methods for reading from Azure table storage are implemented. For example, the most basic query on a table is typically done using the CloudTable.ExecuteQuery method, but that method isn't exposed to UWP apps. In fact, the only query method that seems to be implemented is CloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync which is overkill for a simple query that returns 5 or 10 rows and will never need a token.

Is the storage SDK not the preferred means of UWP apps interacting with table storage? Is the SDK assuming that all UWP apps will ever need is tokenized and segmented queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UWP 10 apps are not yet officially supported by Azure Storage Client.

However, yes, our current Universal support has the maximal support overload ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync. ExecuteQuery returns a lazy enumerable, and lazy enumerables do not exist in an Async paradigm.

Our support for Universal apps is only async at this time.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Now I just need to figure out how to cast the return correctly and I'll be good to go!

Comment: @Peter - is this still the case?  I'm using WindowsAzure.Storage version 8.1.1

Answer (score 1):

SDK methods are just a "shortcut". Under the hood them call Azure API. So you can create your queries and run directly over Azure REST API.

More info, check official doc:

Table Service REST API

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179423

Query Tables

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179405.aspx

Comment: Thanks- Would you recommend making the REST calls directly or using something like RestSharp?

Comment: with both you'll use HTTP. So it's up to you use RestSharp or WebRequest. In the end, restsharp will fire http requests using WebRequest from System.Net. So, it doesn't matter ;)